# After flagging a question, parenthesis are appearing

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, user-interface

I flagged a question as off topic / opinion based. After the flag was submitted, parenthesis appeared next to the option to flag the post. These disappear when the question is reloaded.

[image: Extra Parenthesis]

I am using Firefox 25.0.

Comment: Weird, I just flagged an answer for moderation attention, and don't see the parentheses.  I wonder if it's for questions only, or a specific browser?

Comment: @LBT I just could reproduce this by flagging a question, but not by flagging an answer; seems to be question only.

Comment: Repo-ed on a site that I don't have close privileges and flagging-to-close.  I'm going to guess that it is related to the handling of flag-to-close as similar to close votes

Comment: Just noticed the same as @psubsee2003 here on meta. I don't have close-priveleges here either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately it wasn't caching *this time*, but just a minor [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) glitch.

Fixed in the first `2013.11.14.*` build rev, that rolls out today.

Comment: Don't you mean [tag:jquery] bug? :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd jQuery is not the problem. jQuery is the **solution**.